# Looping through JSON response from desk.com API

Tags: php, json, api

I'm relatively new to JSON decoding, but I've been able to do it using this format (see below) for my looping and it doesn't seem to work for the desk.com api. Not sure if it's because the complexity of the JSON response doesn't like my formatting, or there is a better way to get the key->value pairs.

Here is the JSON response for this API call (http://dev.desk.com/API/topics/#list):

```
{"total_entries":4,"_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/v2/topics?page=1&per_page=50","class":"page"},"first":{"href":"/api/v2/topics?page=1&per_page=50","class":"page"},"last":{"href":"/api/v2/topics?page=1&per_page=50","class":"page"},"previous":null,"next":null},"_embedded":{"entries":[{"name":"Privacy & Security","description":"Information about your privacy.","position":1,"allow_questions":false,"in_support_center":true,"created_at":"2013-02-10T04:40:05Z","updated_at":"2013-09-26T00:12:13Z","_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/445877","class":"topic"},"articles":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/445877/articles","class":"article"},"translations":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/445877/translations","class":"topic_translation"}}},{"name":"Canned Responses","description":"Internal responses to common questions","position":3,"allow_questions":true,"in_support_center":false,"created_at":"2013-02-10T04:40:05Z","updated_at":"2013-09-26T00:31:25Z","_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/445878","class":"topic"},"articles":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/445878/articles","class":"article"},"translations":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/445878/translations","class":"topic_translation"}}},{"name":"FAQ","description":"Frequently Asked Questions","position":2,"allow_questions":false,"in_support_center":true,"created_at":"2013-02-10T04:40:05Z","updated_at":"2013-10-15T00:47:09Z","_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/445879","class":"topic"},"articles":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/445879/articles","class":"article"},"translations":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/445879/translations","class":"topic_translation"}}},{"name":"Suggestions & Feedback","description":"","position":4,"allow_questions":true,"in_support_center":true,"created_at":"2013-07-03T05:27:56Z","updated_at":"2013-10-16T02:38:11Z","_links":{"self":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/538220","class":"topic"},"articles":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/538220/articles","class":"article"},"translations":{"href":"/api/v2/topics/538220/translations","class":"topic_translation"}}}]}}
```

Here is how I was decoding and looping through to get to the NAME value:

```
$topics = json_decode($response);

foreach ($topics as $topic) {
    echo "Name: " . $topic->_embedded->entries->name;
}
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Reading the json string is kinda not easy. Can our post var_dump($topics) here?

Comment: ok, i didn't see the link. ignore my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$entries = $topics->_embedded->entries; // 'entries' from the json response is an array. 
$i = 0;
while(isset($entries[$i])) { // Loop through the array to pick up all the data you need 
 $data[$i][0] = $entries[$i]->name;
 $data[$i][1] = $entries[$i]->description;
 $data[$i][2] = $entries[$i]->_links->self->href;
 $i++;
}
var_dump($data) // Array with all the data. Note that this is now a 2-d array.
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks @om_deshpande -- This works sort of, still get an error, but it outputs the names properly after that. Looks like this.

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /Library/WebServer/Documents/afty/help/desk_api.php on line 125 array(5) { [0]=> string(18) "Privacy & Security" [1]=> string(16) "Canned Responses" [2]=> string(3) "FAQ" [3]=> string(22) "Suggestions & Feedback" [4]=> string(7) "General" }

Comment: @JeffSolomon ahh ok. Made a small edit. Added isset() inside the while statement. Should work now.

Comment: sorry @om_deshpande, one other question. In using your format I'm able to get the single element of "NAME" but if I want other elements from the JSON response within the ENTRIES for example like "description" for example which is the next element, I don't see how to do that with your formatting. Thanks for continued help.

Comment: @JeffSolomon if you want all other elements within ENTRIES, you can run a foreach loop inside the while loop. If you want just one or two others, you can specify each in a separate line inside the while loop - $name[$i][0] = $entries[$i]->name; $name[$i][1] = $entries[$i]->description; Let me know which one of the above are you looking for; I'll update the code in my answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you @om_deshpande, yes, just looking for one or two other elements from the list within ENTRIES, most importantly NAME, DESCRIPTION and topic id (which i think is pulled from _links->self->href as shown in the API documentation - http://dev.desk.com/API/topics/#list

Comment: @JeffSolomon Made a few edits to the answer, for you to be able to pick up more data from ENTRIES.

Comment: Thank you thank you!!!! I'm such a novice... it's annoying, but I'm learning. Thanks @om_deshpande